# Is YouTube Data API v3 webhook available?

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to make a system where I fetch all YouTube comments 
using YouTube v3 API and my agents will reply to those comments from the system and that's will be published into YouTube.
Now the problem is if I want to get all comments in a short time then every time I have to crawl all videos and comment's for checking a new comment. Which is very costly in API calls.

Now I'm searching for webhooks, which will notify or send me the new comment, expecting like what I get from Facebook Webhooks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YouTube webhook for comment or like Not available yet. Only way to hit their server for find new comment. It's have a API which give all comment of a channel.

Answer (score 1):

As you said there isn't any such YouTube webhook to get notified when a new comment is posted.

However I would recommend you to use [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list) with `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId` which has by default order `time` (most recent first). Likewise by just making a single YouTube Data API v3 request periodically you will get fastly and without spending a lot of your quota the latest comments on your YouTube channel (on your videos and also on you "Community" tab). If more than `maxResults` (maximum 50) comments are published during a period you can use `nextPageToken` to continue to browse these new comments.

Comment: Right now I'm use `allThreadsRelatedToChannelId` but problem is I have to call this interval period. and maximum time I get result there don't have any new comment. which is expensive for quota and server.